# How to pass the Row or Row Id to the Custom Checkbox component in MUI DataGridPro?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, customization, mui-x-data-grid

I want to customise the Checkbox component of MUI DataGrid and I'm using DataGridPro version. Want to pass the Row or Row Id to that Custom Checkbox component.
I see there is a componentProps prop in DataGrid but can't figure out a way to pass the Row Id to the custom Checkbox component. Can someone please help me with this?

```js
<DataGridPro
  rows={data}
  components={{
    BaseCheckbox: CustomCheckbox
  }}
  componentsProps={{
    baseCheckbox: {row.id}            //something like this
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define your custom Checkbox component, `CustomCheckbox`, which will receive the row ID as a prop:

```
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';

const CustomCheckbox = ({ rowId, ...props }) => {
  // Use the rowId prop as needed
  // ...
  
  return <Checkbox {...props} />;
};
```

2. In your DataGridPro component, use the `componentsProps` prop to pass the row ID to the `CustomCheckbox` component:

```
<DataGridPro
  rows={data}
  components={{
    BaseCheckbox: CustomCheckbox
  }}
  componentsProps={{
    baseCheckbox: { rowId: (params) => params.row.id }
  }}
/>
```

In the `componentsProps` prop, you can provide a function that receives `params` as an argument. The `params` object contains information about the current cell, including the `row` object. By accessing `params.row.id`, you can retrieve the row ID and pass it as a prop to your custom Checkbox component.

Make sure to update the `...` in the `CustomCheckbox` component with the necessary logic or styling based on the `rowId` prop.